# How do you do a SQL style 'IN' statement in LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework) if Contains isn't supported?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using LINQ to Entities (not LINQ to SQL) and I'm having trouble creating an 'IN' style query.  Here is my query at the moment:

```
var items = db.InventoryItem
                .Include("Kind")
                .Include("PropertyValues")
                .Include("PropertyValues.KindProperty")
                .Where(itm => valueIds.Contains(itm.ID)).ToList<InventoryItem>();
```

When I do this however, the following exception is thrown:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(Int64)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Does anyone have a workaround or another solution for this?

Comment: What is the type of `valueIds`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to either use this one:

```
.Where(string.Format("it.ID in {0}", string.Join(",", valueIds.ToArray())));
```

or construct the WHERE part dynamically, as in [this](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3917617&SiteID=1) post.

### P.S. - Information has been updated and this answer updated as follows to maintain relevance:

The link referenced contains the following update:

> *...in EF4 we added support for the* 
>   *Contains method and at least in this* 
>   *specific case for collection-valued* 
>   *parameters. Therefore this kind of* 
>   *code now works right out of the box* 
>   *and it is not necesary to use any* 
>   *additinal expression building method:*

```
var statusesToFind = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
var foos = from foo in myEntities.Foos
           where statusesToFind.Contains(foo.Status)
           select foo;
```

Comment: I noticed that even by passing in the where as a string, an IN gets converted to many OR statements..

Comment: @liggett78 I'm faced with this situation now due to a custom ORM not supporting `.Contains` or `.Any`. I'm attempting to implement the first solution, but I'm not sure how it works - how does the `.Where` clause accept a non-function argument?

Answer (score 8):

You can use Linq's `Any` extension method for this in some cases:

```
var userIds = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

from u in Users
     where userIds.Any(i => i==u.Id)
     select u;
```

The generated SQL looks pretty strange in such a case, but like much Linq-to-Entities generated SQL it might be overly verbose for a human, but runs fast in practice.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName], 
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            2 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        3 AS [C1]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]) AS [UnionAll2]
    WHERE [UnionAll2].[C1] = [Extent1].[Id]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Diego B Vega in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/) (second answer), `Contains` should now work in EF4.

Answer (score -5):

My workaround is to convert the entities result to a List and **after** that apply the Contains().

Example:

```
var items = db.InventoryItem
                .Include("Kind")
                .Include("PropertyValues")
                .Include("PropertyValues.KindProperty")
                .ToList()
                .Where(itm => valueIds.Contains(itm.ID));
```

Comment: That's awful, sometimes I really hate the hoops EF makes you jump through to do things. But it works for, just looks bad in the code.
Thanks

Comment: In fact this "workaround" takes all data from the database and filters it in C#. If you have a lot of data, it would effectively bring performance down.

Comment: -1: you do not want to hydrate the collection before applying an additional filter.