# Using Entity Framework how do I filter by a foreign key using multiple enumeration values?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Two tables (MainTable and EventType). EventType is represented in code as an enumeration and is foreign keyed in the database so that it looks like;

```
Public enum EventTypeId As Integer
    Blah = 1
    Blurgh = 2
    Whoo = 3
End Enum
```

I can run the following query fine;

```
From M in dbx.MainTable Where M.EventType.EventTypeId = 1
```

But I can't do this (psuedo code);

```
From M in dbx.MainTable Where M.EventType.EventTypeId.Contains(EventTypeId.Blah,EventTypeId.Whoo)
```

The 2nd approach is more readable and maintainable as it links to the enum, but I can't find a construct in EF that allows me to do this.

This is the current version of EF, not .Net 4.0.

In summary, what I want to do in SQL is easy, it just needs to be in EF;

```
Select * From MainTable Where EventTypeId In (1,3);
```

Comment: I found [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328600/how-do-you-do-a-sql-style-in-statement-in-linq-to-entities-entity-framework-i) about the IN-statement in LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at what you want:

> In summary, what I want to do in SQL is easy, it just needs to be in
>   EF;
>
> ```
> Select * From MainTable Where EventTypeId In (1,3);
> ```

you should explain it as: EventTypeId **should be part of** (1,3).
The equivalent for this is: **(1,3) contains EventTypeId**

What you are trying is:

> But I can't do this (psuedo code)
>
> ```
> From M in dbx.MainTable Where M.EventType.EventTypeId.Contains(EventTypeId.Blah,EventTypeId.Whoo)
> ```

But then you are trying: EventTypeId **contains** (1,3)

The solution is todo what you actually want in SQL in the contains syntax, but turn it around: you should look for **(1,3) contains EventTypeId**

So create a list of int with the specific EventType id's you are looking for.
And then filter all records where EventTypeId is part of the list of id's

```
List<int> eventTypeIds = new List<int>();
eventTypeIds.Add((int)EventTypeId.Blah);
eventTypeIds.Add((int)EventTypeId.Whoo);

From M in dbx.MainTable Where eventTypeIds.Contains(M.EventTypeId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Never tried something similar, but have you tested if it works by casting your enumerations to integers, as the following?

```
(int)EventTypeID.Blah
```

Sorry, can't help much more than this without trying for myself, what is not possible right now.

Comment: Nope, it hates that too as it tries to do it db side and complains that it does not know about the type.